# Problems with PyQT4 Library

Tags: python, pyqt4

I installed PyQT4 library from http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download( Binary Packages section).
I have Python 2.7.

I'm trying to get on my PyQT4 and It didnt work!
I tried:
import qt
import pyqt4
import pyqt

And it didnt found!

What would do?

Comment: What didn't work? Did you get an error? What was the message?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
```

Comment: didnt work..

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
ImportError: No module named PyQt4

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one python installation maybe PyQt got installed onto one you aren't using. Anyway, if you installed PyQt4 there must be a directory with that name somewhere in your drive. Do a search and find it. It should be under one of your python installations. Does that directory show up in your `sys.path` or PYTHONPATH variable? This should give you a clue. Maybe you should reinstall and make sure that it goes to the right directory?